# large titles with search bar animation glitch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When going back from view controller with:

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

to view controller with:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

in viewDidLoad I have a strange animation glitch on navigation bar - a white stripe appears

It's appears only when searchBar is visible

[image: animation recording]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped was to add this in viewController with largeTitles enabled:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let navigationBack = UIView()
    navigationBack.frame = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)!
    navigationBack.frame.size.height = 44
    navigationBack.backgroundColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
    let containerView = transitionCoordinator?.containerView

    transitionCoordinator?.animateAlongsideTransition(in: containerView, animation: { (context) in
        containerView?.addSubview(navigationBack)
        navigationBack.frame.size.height = (self.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.frame.height)! + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!
    }, completion: { (context) in
        navigationBack.removeFromSuperview()
    })

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

and this in viewController with largeTitles disabled:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let navigationBack = UIView()
    navigationBack.frame = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame ?? CGRect.zero
    navigationBack.backgroundColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
    let containerView = transitionCoordinator?.containerView

    transitionCoordinator?.animateAlongsideTransition(in: containerView, animation: { (context) in
        containerView?.addSubview(navigationBack)
        navigationBack.frame.size.height = 44
    }, completion: { (context) in
        navigationBack.removeFromSuperview()
    })

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found problem in appear transition, there are some clear space between navigationbar and searchbar. They have independent animation. [Here is it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul9ia.png)
So, you can add common background for them throw transition in "viewWillAppear" method using transitionCoordinator. [That its view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOiNF.png)

**edited**: strong text add logic, when your transition from search table, and navigation is hide at this moment. (searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let navigationBack = UIView()
    if navigationItem.searchController?.isActive == false {
        navigationBack.frame = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame ?? CGRect.zero
    }
    navigationBack.backgroundColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
    let containerView = transitionCoordinator?.containerView

    transitionCoordinator?.animateAlongsideTransition(in: containerView, animation: { (context) in
        containerView?.addSubview(navigationBack)
        navigationBack.frame.size.height += self.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.frame.height ?? 0
    }, completion: { (context) in
        navigationBack.removeFromSuperview()
    })

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set background color of navigation controller view to the same color of navigation bar seems to work around the issue for me.

```
navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
```